# Populate Tkinter Treeview Hierarchically from Directory List

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to populate a tkinter treeview hierarchically from a list of directories that looks like this:

```
C:/1/1
C:/1/2/1
C:/1/2/2
C:/1/3
C:/2
```

You get the idea... The hard part is to relate the next item to its parent.
I tried following something like this: https://python-commandments.org/tkinter-treeview-widget/ but it creates the list on the fly and check for children and so on... But I already have that list.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: I wanted this: https://ibb.co/1zb4PSH
But I solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I wanted this result: https://ibb.co/1zb4PSH

I dit it by 'walking' on each subpath of the pathlist, checking if it already exists, if not, create it on the Treeview and assigning its full path as its ID. Then using that ID to insert other folders and subfolders.

The code:

```
    # Adiciona os projetos TQS na árvore
    # Insere a pasta raiz
    self.tree.insert('', 'end', iid=self.tqs_path, text=self.tqs_path,
        open=True)
    # Insere os projetos TQS
    path_depth = len(self.tqs_path.split(os.path.sep))
    for project in projects:
        project_split = project.split(os.path.sep)
        project_depth = len(project_split)
        for i in range(project_depth):
            if i < path_depth:
                continue
            current_folder = '\\'
            current_folder = current_folder.join(project_split[:i])
            if self.tree.exists(current_folder):
                continue
            else:
                self.tree.insert(os.path.dirname(current_folder),
                'end',
                current_folder,
                text=os.path.basename(current_folder))
        self.tree.insert(os.path.dirname(project),'end',project,
            text=os.path.basename(project))
```